# PHP accessing external server within script slow in multiples of 5 seconds

Tags: php, plesk

I have a server that is slow when I use PHP functions that access an external URL. This happens with all access commands such as:

file
curl
gethostbyname

I have made a simple benchmark script below:

```
<?php
// access time issues
for ($loop=0; $loop<5; $loop++)
{
$start          = gettimeofday(true);
gethostbyname("https://www.google.com");
$end            = gettimeofday(true);
$request_time   = $end - $start;

echo "$request_time<br>";
}
?>
```

If I run this on server #1 (cpannel + centos) I get this output:

```
0.00153994560242
5.00679016113E-6
1.90734863281E-6
2.14576721191E-6
1.19209289551E-6
```

If I run on server #2 (plesk + centos) I get this output:

```
10.01299905777
5.0129120349884
5.0128300189972
5.0093011856079
5.0128750801086
```

Server #1 is very quick, server #2 is slow. The times are suspicious as the delay is always 5.x or 10.x. It will never return 2 seconds for example.

Therefore something is delaying the access by 5 seconds before retrying.

Could this be:
PHP?
Server configuration?
Data centre issue?
Something else?

Your ideas would allow be to at least start looking in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the 2 servers using the same code?

Comment: Yes, the code snippet is copied on both

Comment: Try with a baseline, e.g., a simple php script that just echoes something and compare how long that takes. Then you can determine if the delay is because of specs or other reasons.

Comment: Server 1 screen echo = 3.50475311279E-5 | Server 2 = 1.0967254638672E-5 so is the external URL request that is the issue

Comment: Well then it does depend on the link speed between the server and the other server. We use Amazon Web services and accessing them outside their availability zone is much slower than within.